# Svelte redirect to Microsoft Entra ID fails due to CORS

Tags: azure-active-directory, svelte, openid-connect, microsoft-entra-id

I am building a Svelte application, where the user must login using  Microsoft Entra ID.
I have made a hooks.server.ts file, which checks all traffic for a access token.
If access token is not present the user must redirect to Microsoft for authentication.

This works fine when I redirect to page with page.server.ts file, then I am allowed to redirect to Microsoft.

However, it fails because of CORS in the case that client-side svelte (+page.svelte) makes a GET request to the server-side (+server.ts). Here the hooks.server.ts will notice the token is expired and try and redirect the user to Microsoft Entra ID, but it fails now because of CORS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGFwg.png)

The application uses SvelteKit to navigate between pages and handle client, server-side logic.
I use redirect to navigate from hooks.server.js to Microsoft Entra ID.

import { redirect, type Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

I want to always be able to redirect to Microsoft Entra ID for access and id token.

Comment: AAD is Azure Active Directory? (its new name is Entra ID)

Comment: You are right, I updated the post to include Entra ID instead.